# Ext JS accessing view and store from callback

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I writing the code of a ExtJS controller often happen that I need to access the store or the view from a callback function. The problem is that these references are in the scope of the controller and not in the scope of the function.
For example if I want to reload the data of a grid I write a new record successfully:

```
    record.set(values);
    record.save( {
        callback: function(record, operation) {
            if (operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                Ext.Msg.alert("OK","User Created");
                var view=   Ext.getCmp('contactlist');
                view.getStore().load();
                            view.refresh();
            } else {
              Ext.Msg.alert("Error",operation.request.scope.reader.jsonData["error"]);
            }
    }});
```

After the user is created I want to refresh my store but I cannot use the view and store controller field since I'm in a different scope.
Since now I use `Ext.getCmp()` to retrieve any component? Is this a good practice, which is the best way to solve these situations?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `Ext.getStore('your.store.name');` to get the reference to the store and call whatever methods you want on it.
Calling `reload()` on the store will fire the load event, which for things like grid views will trigger the view refresh

Comment: That's ok but I war really looking for it's a way to avoid using the globals methods like Ext.getStore or Ext.getCmp. Is this considered  a good practice, is there any other way to refer to the crontoller in which the funcion is defined?

Comment: As record.save contains parameters for an Operation object and the object is passed as the second argument to the callback, you may try to add an additional field to the config, say, 'store'. Then in the callback you will use it as operation.store.

Comment: @Panciz if you define your store in the controllers config e.g. `stores: ['MyStoreName']`,  then Ext will generate getters in the form: `getMyStoreNameStore()` [the sencha docs cover this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller).  Maybe that is more what you're looking for.